# Filter an array of points in JavaScript using a margin

Tags: javascript, arrays, opencv, svg, filter

I'm using openCV.js to find contours in an image, after which I apply some filters and simplification to those contours, then draw them as paths in an svg to plot with a pen plotter. I'm having trouble with one filter to remove points from generated points array that fall between the SVG bounds and the margin. I know that a clipping path would do this easily in the final result, but that only solve the problem visually. I need the paths themselves to not include those points so that a pen plotter won't draw them. The current part of the code that is filtering my data is seen below.
("margin" that I was talking about is set by a slider earlier in the code, referenced below as marginSlider.value)

```
      // get contour points and push to array
      let points = [];
      for (let j = 0; j < contours.size(); ++j) {
        const ci = contours.get(j);
        points[j] = [];
        for (let k = 0; k < ci.data32S.length; k += 2) {
          let p = [];
          p[0] = parseInt(ci.data32S[k]);
          p[1] = parseInt(ci.data32S[k + 1]);
          points[j].push(p);
        }
      }
      // filter out contours with less than minNumPointsInContour (usually < 4)
      let fPoints = points.filter(function (element) {
        return element.length >= minNumPointsInContour;
      });
      // filter out points that fall between margin and SVG edge(THIS IS THE PROBLEM SPOT)
      let mFPoints = fPoints.filter(
        (element) => element[0] >= marginSlider.value
      );
      // simplify points before drawing
      let sFPoints = [];
      mFPoints.forEach((element) => {
        let simplifiedPoints = simplify(element, toleranceSlider.value, true);
        sFPoints.push(simplifiedPoints);
      });
```

The main problem spot is `let mFPoints = fPoints.filter((element) => element[0] >= marginSlider.value);`- Currently I'm under the impression that this is only checking the x value of every element in the array and seeing if it is greater than or equal to margin. But i don't know how to make it check 4 things over 1.
Since `fPoints` is a nested array containing point data, the array is organized as `[[0,0],[10,10],[10,20],etc]` (I know, I know, it would be better if they were an object with x and y labels but I have to flatten the thing at the end to parse into an SVG path so, nope).The output at that stage looks like:

```
[
    [
        [
            860,
            296
        ],
        [
            855,
            301
        ],
        [
            854,
            301
        ],
        [
            853,
            302
        ],
        [
            852,
            302
        ],
        [
            851,
            303
        ],
        [
            850,
            303
        ],
        [
            849,
            304
        ],
        [
            848,
            304
        ],
        [
            846,
            306
        ],
        [
            846,
            307
        ],
        [
            882,
            307
        ],
        [
            883,
            306
        ],
        [
            886,
            306
        ],
        [
            887,
            305
        ],
        [
            887,
            302
        ],
        [
            882,
            297
        ],
        [
            880,
            297
        ],
        [
            879,
            296
        ],
        [
            875,
            296
        ],
        [
            874,
            297
        ],
        [
            863,
            297
        ],
        [
            862,
            296
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            0,
            0
        ],
        [
            0,
            1619
        ],
        [
            1079,
            1619
        ],
        [
            1079,
            0
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            149,
            146
        ],
        [
            150,
            145
        ],
        [
            659,
            145
        ],
        [
            660,
            146
        ],
        [
            671,
            146
        ],
        [
            672,
            145
        ],
        [
            673,
            146
        ],
        [
            685,
            146
        ],
        [
            686,
            145
        ],
        [
            689,
            145
        ],
        [
            690,
            146
        ],
        [
            696,
            146
        ],
        [
            697,
            145
        ],
        [
            755,
            145
        ],
        [
            756,
            146
        ],
        [
            761,
            146
        ],
        [
            762,
            145
        ],
        [
            928,
            145
        ],
        [
            929,
            146
        ],
        [
            930,
            146
        ],
        [
            933,
            149
        ],
        [
            933,
            151
        ],
        [
            934,
            152
        ],
        [
            934,
            180
        ],
        [
            933,
            181
        ],
        [
            933,
            194
        ],
        [
            934,
            195
        ],
        [
            934,
            306
        ],
        [
            933,
            307
        ],
        [
            933,
            321
        ],
        [
            932,
            322
        ],
        [
            932,
            331
        ],
        [
            933,
            332
        ],
        [
            933,
            335
        ],
        [
            934,
            336
        ],
        [
            934,
            348
        ],
        [
            933,
            349
        ],
        [
            933,
            359
        ],
        [
            934,
            360
        ],
        [
            934,
            362
        ],
        [
            933,
            363
        ],
        [
            933,
            368
        ],
        [
            934,
            369
        ],
        [
            934,
            481
        ],
        [
            933,
            482
        ],
        [
            933,
            483
        ],
        [
            934,
            484
        ],
        [
            934,
            645
        ],
        [
            933,
            646
        ],
        [
            933,
            652
        ],
        [
            934,
            653
        ],
        [
            934,
            685
        ],
        [
            933,
            686
        ],
        [
            933,
            695
        ],
        [
            934,
            696
        ],
        [
            934,
            732
        ],
        [
            933,
            733
        ],
        [
            933,
            755
        ],
        [
            934,
            756
        ],
        [
            934,
            797
        ],
        [
            933,
            798
        ],
        [
            933,
            839
        ],
        [
            934,
            840
        ],
        [
            934,
            863
        ],
        [
            933,
            864
        ],
        [
            933,
            903
        ],
        [
            934,
            904
        ],
        [
            934,
            1086
        ],
        [
            933,
            1087
        ],
        [
            933,
            1090
        ],
        [
            934,
            1091
        ],
        [
            934,
            1128
        ],
        [
            933,
            1129
        ],
        [
            933,
            1137
        ],
        [
            934,
            1138
        ],
        [
            934,
            1150
        ],
        [
            933,
            1151
        ],
        [
            933,
            1154
        ],
        [
            934,
            1155
        ],
        [
            934,
            1335
        ],
        [
            933,
            1336
        ],
        [
            933,
            1349
        ],
        [
            932,
            1350
        ],
        [
            932,
            1379
        ],
        [
            933,
            1380
        ],
        [
            933,
            1417
        ],
        [
            934,
            1418
        ],
        [
            934,
            1419
        ],
        [
            933,
            1420
        ],
        [
            933,
            1451
        ],
        [
            934,
            1452
        ],
        [
            934,
            1468
        ],
        [
            933,
            1469
        ],
        [
            933,
            1470
        ],
        [
            930,
            1473
        ],
        [
            929,
            1473
        ],
        [
            928,
            1474
        ],
        [
            865,
            1474
        ],
        [
            864,
            1473
        ],
        [
            762,
            1473
        ],
        [
            761,
            1474
        ],
        [
            522,
            1474
        ],
        [
            521,
            1473
        ],
        [
            519,
            1473
        ],
        [
            518,
            1474
        ],
        [
            323,
            1474
        ],
        [
            322,
            1473
        ],
        [
            301,
            1473
        ],
        [
            300,
            1474
        ],
        [
            254,
            1474
        ],
        [
            253,
            1473
        ],
        [
            247,
            1473
        ],
        [
            246,
            1472
        ],
        [
            232,
            1472
        ],
        [
            231,
            1473
        ],
        [
            219,
            1473
        ],
        [
            218,
            1474
        ],
        [
            199,
            1474
        ],
        [
            198,
            1473
        ],
        [
            173,
            1473
        ],
        [
            172,
            1474
        ],
        [
            151,
            1474
        ],
        [
            150,
            1473
        ],
        [
            149,
            1473
        ],
        [
            146,
            1470
        ],
        [
            146,
            1469
        ],
        [
            145,
            1468
        ],
        [
            145,
            1320
        ],
        [
            146,
            1319
        ],
        [
            146,
            1296
        ],
        [
            145,
            1295
        ],
        [
            145,
            1003
        ],
        [
            146,
            1002
        ],
        [
            146,
            987
        ],
        [
            147,
            986
        ],
        [
            147,
            982
        ],
        [
            146,
            981
        ],
        [
            146,
            978
        ],
        [
            145,
            977
        ],
        [
            145,
            599
        ],
        [
            146,
            598
        ],
        [
            146,
            588
        ],
        [
            145,
            587
        ],
        [
            145,
            150
        ],
        [
            146,
            149
        ],
        [
            146,
            148
        ],
        [
            148,
            146
        ]
    ]
]
```

What I would like to do is filter the fPoints array to only include points that the:

- x value `(fPoints[0])` is greater than margin
- x value `(fPoints[0])` is less than svg width- margin
- y value `(fPoints[1])` is greater than margin
- y value `(fPoints[1])` is less than svg width- margin

something about needing to check 2 different values in a nested array is really throwing me for a loop.

The full code is [here](https://github.com/adworetzky/Line-Drawing/blob/svgjs-library/js/script.js) if i didn't include enough information

Comment: Just list all your conditions, connected with a [`&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND) operator. No paranthesis needed.

Comment: That doesn't seem to answer the question. I'm looking for clarification on filtering a nested array based on 2 separate values.

Answer (score 0):

```
  // filter out points that fall between margin and SVG edge
  // assumes outputSVG to be a SVG.js SVG.Svg object
  let mFPoints = fPoints.filter(
    (element) => element[0] >= marginSlider.value &&
                 element[0] <= outputSVG.viewbox().width - marginSlider.value &&
                 element[1] >= marginSlider.value &&
                 element[1] <= outputSVG.viewbox().height - marginSlider.value
  );
```